# Surge Voltage Protection

Tags: circuit-design, safety, circuit-protection, surge-protection, over-voltage-protection

I am currently working on designing a protection circuit for mains power. However, as a hobbyist rather than an expert, I am seeking assistance with this circuit. During my research, I came across an [article](https://www.powerelectronictips.com/what-to-look-for-in-surge-protection-for-power-supplies/) that included the circuit shown below.

[image]

Before proceeding further, I want to mention that the electrical system in my region operates at 220V and 50Hz, with a maximum current of 40A passing through this circuit. I am seeking guidance and assistance from experts to select suitable models for the components shown in the circuit. While I understand the function of each component, I need help determining how to choose the appropriate model for each one so that I can construct the actual circuit.

Additionally, I have a few questions:

1. Why are multiple resistances (RS) placed instead of just one at the entry point of the live line?
2. Why are the MOVs connected between each pair of lines? Would it be better to place just one MOV between Live and Neutral?
3. Similarly, for the TVSs, why are they connected between each pair of lines?

Any insights or guidance on these questions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you working within any particular safety standard e.g. IEC 60950-1? Several components/connections shown above will not be suitable under these standards.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, I am working within IEC 62368. Please mention the components/connections that won't be suitable under this standard.

Answer (score 0):

> *Why are multiple resistances (RS) placed instead of just one at the
> entry point of the live line?*

It's unlikely that they are resistors. It's much more likely that they are fuses.

> *Why are the MOVs connected between each pair of lines?*

They are present on all pairs because of the way that indirect lightning surges can present themselves.

Same response for the TVS diode question.

> *I am seeking guidance and assistance from experts to select suitable
> models for the components shown in the circuit.*

I think you should choose a component type and ask a new question about whether it is suitable. But, before you ask that new question, you should also try and get a copy of EN 61000-4-5 and look at the surge generator circuit to see what surge currents can be present during an indirect lightning strike. Then use a simulator tool to verify that your proposed MOV/TVS can withstand the lightning protection level you are designing for.